# responsive menu media queries

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu

Im really having difficulty making a mobile menu .

When the width is < 500 px , I want the menu collapse and just be a single button

Can anyone help me with the code ? I really made a mess when i tried

a link to the site can be found here.  http://www.lync-star.com/home.html

The css can be found below:

```
body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    /* set the base font to 10px */
}
#header {
    /* section width 100 (0 BM) + clearfix */
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 430px;
    z-index: 20;
    background-color: #000;
}
#wrapper {
    margin: 2em auto;
}
#logocontainer {
    padding: 1em 0;
}
ul {
    /* start Nav */
    height: auto;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
ul li {
    display: inline;
}
ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}
ul a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #00ADF2;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    #wrapper {
        border: 4px solid #000;
        height: 600px;
    }
    #logo {
        height: 7em;
    }
    ul {
        /* start Nav */
        margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
        background-color: #007272;
        font: 1.5em'Oswald', sans-serif;
        min-width: 420px;
    }
    ul li {
        padding: 0 1.6em;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    ul a {
        color: #FFF;
    }
    ul a:hover {
        color: #CCC;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 580px) {
        /* MEDIUM ipad size*/
        #header {
            height: 17.5em;
        }
        ul {
            /* start Nav */
            background: url(images/bgnav1.gif);
        }
        ul li {
            padding: 0 1.3em;
            text-align: left
        }
    }
```

Many thanks, 
P

Comment: Do you notice the syntax error? There is a missing `}` before `@media screen and (min-width: 580px) {`

Comment: can you show the html?

Comment: *I want the menu collapse and just be a single button* .... that will be tricky with just plain CSS ...have you tried with JS ?

Comment: post your html for your nav

Answer (score 0):

Change your media query from min-width to max-width.  Currently, your min-width: 320px is  overwritting your others.

Use for mobile

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
```

And for small

```
@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
```

Then maybe for large

```
@media screen and (min-width: 581px) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your media query per the requirement, this might help you in setting the size for mobile in landscape and portrait view.

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

for more reference you can visit:
http://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints

Answer (score -2):

remove all comments /* MEDIUM ipad size*/ and